# Move object smoothly from start to end of parent without overlap

Tags: css, flexbox, css-calc

I would like to simulate a slider using CSS. [This code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReVWKj) shows a minimum working example.

The `left` property of the slider can be set using javascript or, as in the code pen example, by setting a CSS variable from 0 to 100.

At 0% the slider should sit on the left of its parent. At 100% the slider should sit flush with the right.

The parent is a flex child with its width set by `flex-grow`, and it shares its row with another flex child.

In the image below, the parent of the slider is yellow, and the slider itself is teal. A neighbouring flex child is shown in orange:

[image: Slider at 0%]

When the CSS variable (or Javascript variable) reaches 100%, the slider's right-hand edge should sit flush with the right-hand edge of the yellow box, but currently it moves like this:

[image: 50%]

[image: 100%]

I thought I could calculate the `left` property using something like:

```
calc((100% - 40px) / 100%)
```

But [as MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Syntax), the right-hand side of a division must be a number.

Am I missing something obvious?

```css
.full {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.full p {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 8;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  --complete: 100%;
  left: calc(var(--complete));
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D actually I *didn't* know about Stack Snippets! But now I do. Added one.

Comment: If anyone can think of a better title for this question, please go ahead and edit. I couldn't think of a succinct summary.

Comment: is this what you need:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099457/left-right-movement-css-only-very-generic/51099702#51099702 ?

Comment: and why you need to divide by 100%? calc(100% - 40px) is enough

Comment: @TemaniAfif `calc(100% - 40px)` is no good when complete=0%!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the calculation and remove the percentage from `--complete`:

```
--complete:80;
left: calc( var(--complete) * 1% - var(--complete) * (40px/100));
```

Full code:

```css
.full {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.full p {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 8;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  --complete:80;
  left: calc( var(--complete) * 1% - var(--complete) * (40px/100));
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:100">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:50">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:20">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or combine it with transform and use it like this:

```
--complete: 80%;
left: calc(var(--complete)); 
transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--complete)));
```

```css
.full {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.full p {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 8;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: orange;
}

.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  --complete: 80%;
  left: calc(var(--complete));
  transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--complete)));
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:0%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:50%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="full">
  <div class="left">
    <p>flex-grow: 8</p>
    <div class="slider" style="--complete:20%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>flex-grow: 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a useful tip-off from [Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) about [using translateX as well as left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099702/2071807), I have managed to put together a solution which isn't pretty, but works.

I'm still open to more 'attractive' solutions.

```
.slider {
  position: relative;
  --complete: 100;
  left: calc(1% * var(--complete));
  transform: translateX(calc(-40px * var(--complete) / 100));
}
```