# jQuery Marquee scrolling text won't work within a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bootstrap modal which i want the marquee scrolling text in. However, it works outside of the modal, but not within it.

`<marquee class="section-flash-marquee" behavior="alternate" scrolldelay="100">Bouncing text...</marquee>`

Here is a DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/CxdUQ/3045/

So my question is how do I get the scrolling text working within the modal?

```html
                    <marquee class="section-flash-marquee" behavior="alternate" scrolldelay="100">Bouncing text...</marquee>
```

^^ Or is there a CSS or jQuery way to recreate the above so the text scrolls back and forth?

Thanks

Comment: Look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53421699/6437626) to a similar question and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099702/6437626) to the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

[Marquee is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee), and can have unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the `marquee` is deprecated and may not give the results you require.

There are a few other plugins and libraries out there that you can use to achieve this, or you could roll your own:

[DeSade](https://github.com/MrMichaelNealon/Noktu/blob/master/app/DeSade.js) requires jQuery

I wrote this a while ago, might be useful to you. Never used it with Bootstrap, though - you're welcome to use or modify it if it's any good to you:

```
<script src="DeSade.js"></script>

var duration = 15000;

// Create new instance
var marquis = new DeSade("id_of_parent_container", "id_of_new_marquee_element");
marquis.newMarquis("Text to display", duration);
```

Also pauses the scrolling effect on mouseover, you'll find a demo [here](https://rawgit.com/MrMichaelNealon/Noktu/master/Demo/Noktu.html) -- just play the tracks, marquee scrolls along the top of the audio player.

It was a quick hack for a specific purpose so only goes one direction (right to left) but easy to modify for your purposes.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

As I said in the below comment, something like this could be achieved with pure CSS, here's a very simple example that could be tweaked to suit your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            #outer {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%; left: 0%;
                width: 100%; height: 100%;
            }

            #inner {
                animation: marquee 10.0s infinite;
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #marquee {
                width: auto;
                color: #F00;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes marquee {
                0% { 
                    animation-timing-function: linear;
                    transform: translate(-45%, 0px);
                }
                50% { 
                    animation-timing-function: linear;
                    transform: translate(45%, 0px);
                }
                100% { 
                    animation-timing-function: linear;
                    transform: translate(-45%, 0px);
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
                <div id="marquee">
                    Some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some tricks required to get the desired effect but maybe useful to you - maybe someone else with more CSS skills than myself can come up with something more flexible.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I kind of need one that bounces back on itself like the demo. The examples i have been able to find all seem to go offscreen, then start again.

Comment: You could probably achieve this using CSS3 animations.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a simple example of what you're talking about using basic CSS animation/transitions.