# CSS Text Animation for scrolling text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think I am half way there, but I need some CSS3 or jQuery help to complete this scrolling text.

I have a div, I need the text to scroll from left to right, then when hitting the end of the div scroll right to left again and so on.

I currently have it going from left to right, however it seems to run outside of the div and I don't know how to get it going back right to left, and so on.

Here is a DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/vdb3ofmL/1118/

```
#movetxt {
    -webkit-animation: moving 5s infinite;
    animation: moving 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving {
    from {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translateX(200px);}
}

@keyframes moving {
    from {transform: translateX(0px);}
    to {transform: translateX(200px);}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `position` in CSS3. As you can see, text point is in middle, not at right side.

Comment: Do you want this responsive, or will the container element always be 300px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution is to use `right` and `translateX` in `%` and with `absolute` positioning.

Adding `alternate` to `animation` plays the animation backwards.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
}

#movetxt {
  animation: moving 2s infinite linear alternate;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes moving {
    from {
      transform: translateX(100%);
      right: 100%;
      }
    to {
      transform: translateX(0%);
      right: 0%;
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="movetxt">left to right, right to left</div>
</div>
```