# Trying the native Element.animate method, but cannot add keyframe percentages

Tags: javascript, css

Someone asked a related question and I am trying to make it work with the  experimental technology Element.animate.
The MDN documentation is rather...slim and the state of the technology is lets say infantile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

What I have is this markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="movetxt">left to right, right to left</div>
</div>
```

Just want the movetxt div to move from left to right ad infinity within the container div.

Css is hard coded, as I do not know how to get the width of the div text node.

```
.container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

#movetxt {
width: 180px;
}
```

Now, the JS

```
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var movingText = document.getElementById("movetxt");
 var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var textWidth = movingText.offsetWidth;
var totalDistance = containerWidth - textWidth;
var oneWayDistance = totalDistance / 2; //just establishing the travel distance
```

And now the experiment part:

```
 movingText.animate([
// keyframes
{ transform: 'translateX(' + oneWayDistance + 'px)' }, 
{ transform: 'translateX(-' + totalDistance + 'px)' }
], { 
// timing options
duration: 1000,
iterations: Infinity
});
```

This kind of works, the console throws some errors, but the thing runs.

But, I want to have this kind of keyframas format, just an example:

```
  0%   { transform: 'translateX(' + oneWayDistance + 'px)' },
        10%  { transform: 'translateX(-' + totalDistance + 'px)' }
```

If I try that, I get Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Keyframes must be objects, or null or undefined.

Link to fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vdb3ofmL/1135/

There must be some way to place the keyframe % values there, can anyone figure this out?

Cheers

Comment: probably talking about this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421475/css-text-animation-for-scrolling-text) where there is an easy CSS solution

Comment: Well, the easy CSS solution is not responsive and the element still overflows.

Comment: And that is besides the point, I am talking about trying this new, potentialy very valuable technology.

Comment: it's responsive, check the duplicate

Comment: It cannot be really responsive when the parent element has a hard coded px width. It is an unsatisfying reply, nobody would deploy that to a live website/app.
If the OP is happy with that answer, fine, but this is a new question with new scope. How to add keyframe % values to the array.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the parent element .. the solution provided doesn't consider any width of the parent element and it uses percentage values only

Comment: Actually, that solution that is posted now is decent.
Ok, back to topic, can we experiment with this Element.animate, this is something that is overdue imo.

Comment: check my answer below ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the fact that the text is initially on the left edge of the container, so you need to translate form `0` to `width of container - width of text`:

And what you are looking for is the `offset` value<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats)</sup>

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var movingText = document.getElementById("movetxt");
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var textWidth = movingText.offsetWidth;
var totalDistance = containerWidth - textWidth;
var oneWayDistance = totalDistance / 2;
console.log(containerWidth);
console.log(textWidth);
movingText.animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'translateX(0)',offset:0 },  /*0%*/
  {  transform: 'translateX(' + totalDistance + 'px)',offset:0.3 }, /*30%*/
  {  transform: 'translateX(0)',offset:1 } /*100%*/
], { 
  // timing options
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#movetxt {
  width: 180px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="movetxt">left to right, right to left</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, yes, offset value was what I was looking for.
Does this stuff work on anything else than Chrome?

Comment: @ptts according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats it may also work on Firefox but it remain experimental, so don't rely on it

Answer (score 1):

You should use offset like this

```
element.animate({
    opacity: [ 0, 0.9, 1 ],
    offset: [ 0, 0.8 ], // Shorthand for [ 0, 0.8, 1 ]
    easing: [ 'ease-in', 'ease-out' ],
}, 2000);
```

and in your case you can use like this and change your own

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var movingText = document.getElementById("movetxt");
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var textWidth = movingText.offsetWidth;
var totalDistance = containerWidth - textWidth;
var oneWayDistance = totalDistance / 2;
movingText.animate(
  {transform:['translateX(' + oneWayDistance + 'px)','translateX(-' + totalDistance + 'px)','translateX(' + oneWayDistance + 'px)'],
  offset: [0,0.1]
}, { 
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#movetxt {
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="movetxt">left to right, right to left</div>
</div>
```