# Animate with animation, transformation, translate HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to move the image linearly from right to left of screen and do it in a loop. HELP but my code is not working properly.
My HTML code.

```
<div class="row">    
   <div class="column">
       <img class="move"  src="image.png" alt="image">
   </div>
```

My Style.css code.

```
.pacman {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    animation: chase 8s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes chase { 
    0% { transform: translateX(100%);}
    50% { transform: translateX(50%);}
    100% { transform: translateX(0%);}
}
```

Comment: TYPO EDIT*: the .pacman class is placed in image tag.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51099457/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform` does not do what you think it does. A transform only affects the visual position of the element respective to *itself*.

To move the element across the page, you have to animate the `right` value.

I've added an extra transform so that the image completely exits the page.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 0%;
  animation: chase 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes chase {
  0% {
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    right: 100%;
    transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/50/50" alt="">
```